# BizTalk - how to subscribe to two-way send ports response, but access data from the request

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

I need to submit something to a web service,  then I need to send something over MLLP using the HL7 MLLP adaptor and the message needs to contain something returned by the service, and something that was sent to the service, and I'd like to use a pure messaging solution if possible, not an orchestration.

So basically I have two send ports.  The second needs to subscribe to the response of the first, which means that it's message will the the first send ports response.

The trick is I also need some data from the first send ports request message.  Is it possible to get that somehow?

Comment: Why don't you want to use an Orchestration?  This scenario sounds like one you should use an Orchestration.  Other than that see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4bdf5b57-abcf-485d-b609-88d1f58ca2c4/access-promoted-property-in-the-response-message-context-on-requestresponse-port?forum=biztalkgeneral

Comment: @Dijkgraaf - we've found orchestrations such a burden to implement an manage, that we don't see in a pure message solution not to mention the performance impact that pure message doesn't have.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf - as i recall there's even some gotchas when building orchestrations, like implementing a specific pattern around the logical send port so that retries can work when the orchestration is suspended.

Comment: There is only a small performance impact from an Orchestration, unless it is very complex.  Usually the Orchestration only suspends after the retries have been exhausted.   In this scenario trying to do messaging only sounds more burdensome than using an Orchestration.  The only other option is to make sure that the values you need are persisted all the way until you need it, either in the messages or the context properties

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is **use an Orchestration.**

*There is nothing wrong with using an Orchestration,* and Orchestrations exist exactly for this purpose.

If someone is telling you Orchestrations are not right or you've read that somewhere...they're wrong.  That's it.  If you're having problems using Orchestrations...telling you straight up, you're doing it wrong.

In an Orchestration, you can probably use a Map to merge the content into the service response.  Exactly the use case it's meant for.

Here's a started Suspend/Resume pattern: [BizTalk Server: Suspend and Resume an Orchestration on Two Way Port Error](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31665.biztalk-server-suspend-and-resume-an-orchestration-on-two-way-port-error.aspx?Sort=MostRecent&PageIndex=1)

You have no control of this in a Messaging only solution.